# print star pattern with interval range output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I have the solution to print star patterns

```
lower = int(input("what is the minimum nmber of stars: "))
upper = int(input("what is the maximum number of stars: "))
interval=int(input("enter the interval:"))

for i in range (lower,upper+1,interval):
    print((lower) * ' ' + i * '*')
```

which only prints out the the stars for example:

```
***
```

what I'm looking for is

```
***(3 stars)

********(7 stars)

***********(11 stars)
```

How do I  print the literal part(x stars)?

Comment: Why are you printing spaces before the stars?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
lower = int(input("what is the minimum nmber of stars: "))
upper = int(input("what is the maximum number of stars: "))
interval=int(input("enter the interval:"))

for i in range (lower,upper+1,interval):
    print(lower*' ' + i*'*', '({} stars)'.format(i))
```

Output:

```
what is the minimum nmber of stars: 1
what is the maximum number of stars: 4
enter the interval:1
 * (1 stars)
 ** (2 stars)
 *** (3 stars)
 **** (4 stars)
```